# VM2 memory leakage

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, node-vm2

How we will solve this problem of memory leakage? When I am hitting 100 concurrent multiple requests, each time VM2 creating new process and memory leakage occur. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Describe your issue in more detail, provide sample data / snapshot

Comment: See, I am running docker container of size 100 mb. And I am hitting 100 multiple request using "Apache Bench" tool, when 92 request done, docker exited with message : connection reset by peer(104). and when I comment all vm2 code, It works perfectly for more than 4000 requests. @Yaman